# StackExchange.Redis Async with Fire and Forget not setting the keys

Tags: c#, async-await, stackexchange.redis, fire-and-forget

I'm trying to figure out when I try to use `Redisclient` with `Async` operations with command flag as Fire and Forget, out of 5 `stringSet` only 3 is getting set 2 strings are not available in the server. Is it right to mix both `Async` and `FireAndForget` ?

Following is the code I tried, when called 5 times I could see only 3 values are set.

```cs
return await _redisDBClient.StringSetAsync(key, value, flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
```

Comment: Is your application exiting before all the commands are actually sent?

Answer (score 0):

`CommandFlags.FireAndForget` is returning immediately so it is meaningless using it with `redis.XxxAsync` calls. In this situation, if redis reply with an error to any of the operations, `StackExchange.Redis` will ignore those errors.

Source: [docs](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/PipelinesMultiplexers.html#fire-and-forget)